# Apache POI for docx Insert Text On Specific Page

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to make Table of Contents for my Word document docx.

Apache POI is still too buggy. The `document.createTOC()` does not produce anything unless placed at the end. Sometimes, it doesn't give the correct page numbers.

The `document.enforceUpdateFields()` doesn't do anything!

So I thought I make my own method that creates the Table of Content. However, I will call it at the end but I need it to be inserted at the beginning!

In other words, suppose my document at some point in my program has some text on the first page and the second page. And I haven't yet saved it; how do I insert at the beginning of first page?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet. But, after you write the document. Reload it again

Then try the following:

```
List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
XWPFRun run = paragraphs.get(0).insertNewRun(0); // first paragraph, 0 is the position
run.setText("your data here");
```

Comment: oh and don't forget to save the document after that!